Group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})$
I'm a little confused solving the following problem:
Determine if $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})$ is a Galois extension for $\mathbb{Q}$.
I understand that now my mission is to find the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})$. Let's get into it!:
First of all I could find the minimal polynomial which is $p(x)=x^4-4x^2+1$. Even more, one can exhibit all the roots of this polynomial: $x_{1,2}=\pm\dfrac{(\sqrt{3}+1)\sqrt{2}}{2}=\pm\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$ and $x_{3,4}=\pm\dfrac{(\sqrt{3}-1)\sqrt{2}}{2}=\pm\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$.
The polynomial $p(x)$ is irreducible by doing $x=t+1$ and applying Eisenstein's criterion.
Here is where my problems start: Automorphisms are determined by their action on the generators, in this case on the element $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$, which can be sent to itself or $-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$. On the other hand, I could show that the roots $\pm\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})$, so I understand that I cannot map $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$ to $\pm\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$. Then I just have two automorphisms and therefore the extension is not Galois because $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}):\mathbb{Q}]=4\neq |Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}))|=2$.
The thing is, I found THIS SITE in which there is a similar problem that consists in finding the automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})$ and he maps the root $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ to any other roots of the polynomial of degree 4. I feel that this exercise is similar but the methods we are using are different.
I enormously appreciate any light on this matter.

We know the Galois group acts transitively on the roots of the minimal polynomial, so there has to be some chain of automorphisms taking $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$ to $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$...

The Galois Group of this polynomial is indeed the Klein-four group, as was noted by @J.W.Tanner in the comments. However, since the task is to verify whether a field is a Galois extension and we are in characteristic 0, the only thing we need to show is that all roots of the minimal polynomial are also in the field, i.e. we show that the field is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$.

If you are familiar with cyclotomic fields you can also make progress using the observation that $$2\cos\frac{\pi}{12}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}.$$
Apply the half-angle formula to $\cos(\pi/6)$, if you haven't seen that before! Anyway, you actually have the other roots $\pm\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}$ in the field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt3})$ as well. Take another look at Lubin's answer :-)

I wrote up a complete answer, and realized that it will be much more fun for you if you do it yourself, noticing that if you call one root of your polynomial $\theta$, then $1/\theta$ is also a root.
If you need help, I can include my writeup.

I would enjoy seeing your writeup,  as you are wildly successful.

Is it significant that $\theta\mapsto\frac1\theta$ is an involution ($\sigma^2=1$)?  (All the automorphisms are?) So the automorphism group is $\mathbb Z_2^2$?

I think I got it. Since $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ is a field, I have the right to take the inverse of $\theta$ and this is in fact the other root that I was missing. Then I will just have to study how this automorphisms behave under composition to conclude. I could not do this if the other roots were complex.  Thanks a lot!

I’ll wait a few days more, @czech-spanier , before posting my contribution, to give OP time and space to get the whole thing himself.

@Lubin I was being facetious

@Lubin:  I seriously enjoy your posts and I’m wondering if my comment is in the direction you were thinking

Maybe I owe an apology, @J.W.Tanner , I sort of left this question fade beyond my horizon. But your comment is exactly the core of my argument.

Thanks @Lubin.  It was fun for me!
